# How to write one to many relationship query of mongodb in python using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, nosql-aggregation

I am new to mongodb and writing a demo code in python using pymongo client for connection between mongodb and python.

I have created two collections with Database named "Mongodb_demo":

```
1. Employee (employeename, sal, employeeid, depid)
2. Department (depid, deptname, dept_description)
```

I need to find the "In which department, employees are highest in number".

I have tried many documentations, but only mongodb environment code is available.
How do I integrate the mongodb query with python code or how do i change the syntax to get the result in python list format.

**Demo data provide below**:

```
**Collection = department**
    {'depid': 1.0, 'deptname': 'Marketing', 'dept_description': 'This is Marketing department.'}
    {'depid': 2.0, 'deptname': 'HR', 'dept_description': 'This is Human Resource department.'}
    {'depid': 3.0, 'deptname': 'Operations', 'dept_description': 'This is Operations department.'}


**Collection = employee**
    {'employeename': 'Rohan Patil', 'sal': 50000.0, 'employeeid': 'rohan.patil.512', 'depid': 2.0}
    {'employeename': 'Goldy Sharma', 'sal': 40000.0, 'employeeid': 'goldy.sharma.513', 'depid': 2.0}
    {'employeename': 'Venugopal Ayeer', 'sal': 45000.0, 'employeeid': 'venugopal.ayeer.511', 'depid': 2.0}
    {'employeename': 'Sudha Murti', 'sal': 45000.0, 'employeeid': 'sudha.murti.514', 'depid': 3.0}
    {'employeename': 'Rajesh Kumar', 'sal': 38000.0, 'employeeid': 'rajesh.kumar.515', 'depid': 1.0}
```

Comment: It's not clear the precise question/help you need.  Can you connect to your MongoDB server with python?  Do you know how to write a query using pymongo?  Do you know how to extract the query results from the returned cursor?  Do you know how to write this specific query?

Comment: my question is, i know how to write query in mongodb. but same query i need to convert in pymongo to work with python code. I am not able to convert the mongodb query in pymongo query.

Comment: Have you reviewed the [`pymongo` tutorial](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)?

Comment: yes, but not getting any proper solution for this kind of aggregation.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed your valid/working `mongosh` (?) code and your `pymongo` code that doesn't work, some helpful suggestions might be possible.